# MySQL Procedure Problem, getting user which i last input all over again

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hello i have a problem with my Mysql procedure, every time I try to insert a new "User" into the table and call after thaht all "Useres" in the table, i get only the Last "User" with a different "id", when i call the queries without a procedure it seems all ok. I have one child table related to the main table.

```
>     CREATE DEFINER=`Marko`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InserUser`( in FirstName varchar(30), in LastName varchar(30), in cityID int ) BEGIN
> insert into Users (FirstName, LastName, cityID) values (FirstName,
> Lastname, cityID); select  Users.id, FirstName, Lastname, city from
> Users inner join citys on Users.cityID = citys.id;
> 
> END
```

Comment: I testet you procedure and it works like intended it inserts data and show all available users

Comment: But what's the point of it?

Comment: I get for every user a different id, but the same name. Example i want to insert "Steven" i just get a lot of  Stevens with different id's. But i want to get all useres from the table back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use prefixes with the parameter names so MySQL is able to distinguish parameters from the column names.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Marko`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InserUser`( 
in_FirstName varchar(30), 
in_LastName varchar(30), 
in_cityID int
) 
BEGIN

insert into Users (FirstName, LastName, cityID) 
values (in_FirstName, in_Lastname, in_cityID); 

select u.id, u.FirstName, u.Lastname, c.city 
from Users u
  inner join citys c on u.cityID = c.id;

END
```